# Getting updated value of state in a javascript file in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vue-reactivity

I am trying to update state variable's value from a vue file and I want that updated value in a javascript file. I am updating value using mutations from vue file but when I retrieve value inside of javascript file it is showing state variable's old value.

code snippets:
1. I am updating a state variable's value from **Sample.vue** file.
2. That gets updated in mutations
3. I want updated state variable's value in **sample.js** which is a javascript file.
4. The last code snippet is of state in which I have declared state variable i.e., in **state.js** file.

```
// Sample.vue 
this.$store.commit('setStateVariable','newValue');
```

```
// mutations.js
setStateVariable(state, payload) {
        state.newValue = payload;
}
```

```
// sample.js
import state from "../store/state";
   console.log(state.newValue);
```

```
// state.js
export default{
newValue: 'Hello World'
}
```

**Note:** Above code snippets are from 4 separate files and included here to just make question more understandable. And there is no import export issue in actual code.
**In a nutshell**, I am not getting updated value of state's variable in javascript file(**NOT VUE FILE**) even though I have updated it from a vue file.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to import the `store` in `sample.js` file and use it like the following `store.state.newValue`.

I've created sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-wozniak-4cyin?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Whoh! great logic. I appreciate it.